# How to get XML data from url with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I want to get XML data The source code of this page but I don't get it. 
I think on this page are the session and I can not for this. I need help

Page : https://www.betorder.com/LiveScore.html?sportTypeId=1

Xml Data : https://www.betorder.com/GetLiveScore?qq=62642&sportTypeId=1&fid=0&lang=TR&countryId=all&checkBoxSelected=all

```
 string adres = "https://www.betorder.com/GetLiveScore?qq=62642&sportTypeId=1&fid=0&lang=TR&countryId=all&checkBoxSelected=all";
    WebRequest gelenIstek = HttpWebRequest.Create(adres);
    WebResponse gelenCevap;
    using (gelenCevap = gelenIstek.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader donenDeger = new StreamReader(gelenCevap.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string gelenBilgi = donenDeger.ReadToEnd();
            string gonder = gelenBilgi;
            div.InnerHtml = gonder;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't told us any of the HTTP error codes or anything else relating to the issue. Are you receiving _anything_ from the server? 

You're not sending any headers to the server so it doesn't know who the request is being made by. Perhaps you need to generate headers with meaningful information.

Comment: No. I can not get data from the server I gave links

Comment: @BahaAdıyaman using your link... there is no XML data. Setting the innerHtml of a `div` to XML probably won't be visible on the page anyway. You'd need to encode it.

Comment: See this link ago : https://www.betorder.com/LiveScore.html?sportTypeId=1

later : https://www.betorder.com/GetLiveScore?qq=62642&sportTypeId=1&fid=0&lang=TR&countryId=all&checkBoxSelected=all

Comment: Well, the whole thing is a flash app so I'm not sure how you're expecting this to just work if you dump it in a div.

Comment: I want to receive XML data in the form. Second there is the XML data in the form